# Did Beethoven ever meet Mozart?

Tags: classical-music, beethoven, mozart

I hear different stories about the different musical intellects of Mozart and Beethoven in their different musical periods. Did they ever meet? What did Beethoven think of Mozart's ideology and pattern of music?

Comment: https://www.oxfordmusiconline.com/grovemusic/display/10.1093/gmo/9781561592630.001.0001/omo-9781561592630-e-0000040026#omo-9781561592630-e-0000040026 _in the spring of 1787 Beethoven visited Vienna. In the absence of documents much remains uncertain about the precise aims of the journey and the extent to which they were realized; but there seems little doubt that he met Mozart and perhaps had a few lessons from him. It seems equally clear that he did not remain in Vienna for longer than about two weeks._

Comment: @user1079505 that's an answer

Answer (score 5):

It's possible they met, but there's no proof.

Beethoven spent a few weeks in Vienna in early 1787 (sources disagree as to exactly when and for how long). Mozart was in Vienna for at least part of early 1787, although he spent some time in Prague, so it's possible they were in Vienna at the same time.

Beethoven held Mozart in very high regard (he'd heard and played a lot of Mozart and several of his works are very obviously inspired by him) and it's very likely he would have sought to arrange a meeting if in fact they were both there simultaneously. Unfortunately, even if if did happen, there is no first-hand account of their meeting. One third-hand account of an alleged meeting places it in the wrong year: 1790.

Further reading: Wikipedia: [Beethoven and Mozart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beethoven_and_Mozart) and 'The Right Notes': [Mozart's influence on Beethoven](https://www.therightnotes.org/mozart-s-influence-on-beethoven.html)

Comment: Thanks for finally answering! I feel like the other thing that's worth calling attention to is how often Beethoven directly quoted or indirectly echoed Mozart, which is one indicator of regard, since part of the OP's question is "and what did he think of his music."

Comment: @AndyBonner The extent of Mozart's influence on Beethoven is covered in detail in the linked articles.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answers and links. Really satisfying.